# CASE WHEN Tests LIKE '%-PAT-[IEG]DR[AVNM]-%' , this is in sql i want to convert this to hive

Tags: sql-server, hive, bigdata, hiveql

Want to add condition to Match letters starting with '-PAT' and any 1 letter from [I,E,G] then again mandatory letter 'DR' and finally any letter out of [A,V,N,M] in hive

Comment: is it hive or sql server?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `RLIKE` operator:

```
CASE WHEN Tests RLIKE '-PAT-[IEG]DR[AVNM]-'
     THEN 'match' ELSE 'no match' END AS label
```